# Get the identity id's from a batch insert into redshift using python psycopg2 execute_values

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, batch-insert

I am currently inserting records in batch to a Redshift (Postgres) db.  I am using the psycopg2.extras.execute_values method as from what I have read, this is the fastest way to do it using the below code constructing a list of tuples which contain the data to insert

```
    dataList = []
    dataList.append(tuple(data.values()))

    insert_query = "insert into " + tableName + " ( " + insert + ") VALUES %s"

    try:
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, insert_query, dataList, template=None, page_size=100)
        con.commit()
```

This works fine, however I need to get back the id's from the identity column on the DB.  I have searched to see if this is possible with this method but cannot find a firm answer on whether this is possible with the the execute_values method?

If not, what is the best way to achieve this batch insert and also retrieve the id's?

Answer (score 2):

Use `returning` and a `page_size` bigger then the batch size:

```
insert_query = "insert into t (c) values %s returning *"
execute_values(cursor, insert_query, data, template=None, page_size=99999)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

If the `page_size` is smaller than the batch size then the cursor content is undefined, probably the last batch.

Comment: After some more research it looks like returning is not supported on Redshift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239986/get-the-the-auto-id-for-inserted-row-into-redshift-table-using-psycopg2-in-pytho